# I have a problem with my if statement, doesn't execute my code correctly in my vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a new system for a client, and I my if statement doesn't to execute correctly on my Customer Form when I press create customer.

I have tried switching to Case Statement didn't resolve my problem, then went back to if statement then I made a line for each of the required fields that needs to be filled. When I get to fill in Account Details Nothing happens as well.

VB.NET

```
If btnNew.Text = "New Customer" Then

    cuscontrol.TabPages.Remove(cuslist)
    cuscontrol.TabPages.Add(cusnew)
    btnNew.Text = "Create Customer"
    btnSMS.Visible = False
    btnMail.Visible = False
    btnDoc.Visible = False
    btnClose.Text = "Cancel"

ElseIf btnNew.Text = "Create Customer" Then

    If cusname.Text = "" Or custype.Text = "" Or paytype.Text = "" Or cname.Text = "" Or idtype.Text = "" Or idno.Text = "" Or title.Text = "" Or cmobile.Text = "" Or cmail.Text = "" Then

        MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Complete Required Fields!", "BMS Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    ElseIf acc.Visible = True Then

        If accno.Text = "" Or accname.Text = "" Or accper.Text = "" Then

            MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Complete Required Fields!", "BMS Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

    ElseIf cntype.Enabled = True Then

        If cntype.Text = "" Then

            MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Complete Required Fields!", "BMS Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

    ElseIf custype.Text = "Business" Then

        If vat.Text = "" Or office.Text = "" Or mail.Text = "" Then

            MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Complete Required Fields!", "BMS Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

    ElseIf custype.Text = "Business" Then

        If vat.Text = "" Or office.Text = "" Or mail.Text = "" Then

            MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Complete Required Fields!", "BMS Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Success")

    End If

End If
```

I don't get any error, nothing happens, the Success MessageBox is suppose to show if the code executed right.

I need my form when I press the Create Customer Button It needs to check if all required fields all filled (I didn't yet start with validation) in. If Null Then MessageBox.Show("Please Complete Required Fields")

Comment: Did you try using Debugger?

Comment: String comparisons are case sensitive by default. Are you sure your button's text value is really `"Create Customer"`?

Comment: Relying on string comparisons of user-facing strings is not a great idea, because they can be changed on a whim. Giving the same button two different purposes is also not a good practice. Consider using two different buttons, one for "Create" and one for "New". You can show and hide them as necessary (instead of changing the text on the one button). This should make your code both clearer and less error-prone, as well as separating the different areas of functionality a bit better.

Comment: if nothing happens i'm guessing both `If btnNew.Text = "New Customer" Then` and `ElseIf btnNew.Text = "Create Customer" Then` evaluate to false, there's no else clause there so nothing happens.
On an unrelated note: you can make your logic slightly more efficient by using `OrElse`instead of `Or`, to avoid redundant checks